# How do I compare sets in one cycle?

Tags: python

I had a task:

> We have a storage set of products N, the store's assortment is a lot of products from this set. The company owns M stores. For the information on the assortment provided by each of these stores, create a program that will form the following sets:
>
> - set A: set of products that all the stores have;
> - B: set of products, each of which is in at least one store;
> - C: set of products that are not in any store.

I tried this:

```
import random

storage = {"tomatoes", "cucumbers", "corn", "oranges", "bananas", "apples", "grapes", "mandarins", "crab sticks", "mayonnaise", "ketchup", "tomato sauce"}
n = int(input("enter number of stores "))
shop = []
k = len(storage)
st_list = list(storage)
stor_del = st_list[random.randint(0, k - 1)]
for i in range(n):
    shop.append(set())
    for j in range(5):
        shop[i].add(st_list[random.randint(0, k - 1)])
    shop[i].discard(stor_del)

    print(shop[i])
```

But I don't know how to do the second part of the task.

Comment: What do you mean by the title of your question? Which sets do you want to compare exactly? What is "one cycle"? Would you be able to solve the task without the requirement of "one cycle"?

Comment: I need to compare the set "shop" "with itself" to find what products are in all stores, or what products are only in one store, or what products are not at all.(Sorry about my English )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of these can be done individually between two stores by using bitwise operators on sets:

- `{a} | {b}` takes the union of the two sets, returning a new set containing every item that either of its arguments contained
- `{a} & {b}` takes the intersection of the two sets, returning a new set containing only items they share
- `{a} ^ {b}` takes the symmetric difference of the two sets, returning a new set containing only elements that either set contains, but not both.

If you have more than two sets (for example, your `shop` is a list of sets), you can use [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to apply the same operator to all of them:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

union = reduce(operator.or_, shop)
intersect = reduce(operator.and_, shop)
sym_diff = reduce(operator.xor, shop)
```

(I use the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) module instead of using lambdas, just because it looks like cleaner code).

Comment: Thank you very much <3